# Powershellscript won't replace this charter '\'. I need it out of the string. Any ideas?

Tags: string, powershell, replace, escaping

If need to get rid of a charter in a string, I normally just use the replace operator. For example:

```powershell
"man" -replace "n", ""   # returns "ma"
```

But when I tried to do something like this:

```powershell
"C:\Users\Public" -replace "\", ""
```

It just throws an error.

What can I do?

I have a script doing something in an order (handed as parameter), saving the result to a text file with the name `pathlistfile.txt`. So in the example I would like a name like `CUsersPubliclistfile.txt`. But I can't to it because I can't replace `\`. What to do?

PS: I already tried to escaping it `` "C:\Users\Public" -replace "`\", "" ``, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You are likely escaping the second `"`. Try `-replace "\\", ""`

Answer (score 4):

As Justin mentions, the `-replace` operator takes a regex as the first parameter.  Try this:

```
"C:\Users\Public" -replace "\\", ""
```

Or if you want a simple replace:

```
"C:\Users\Public".replace("\", "")
```